# How to convert date format from dd/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-dd in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I tired to covert from **21/07/2016** to 2**016-07-21** but got this date **2015-12-20** 
Here is the Code that i have try

```
let inputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYYY"

let outputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

let showDate = inputFormatter.dateFromString("07/21/2016")
let resultString = outputFormatter.stringFromDate(showDate!)

print(resultString)
```

How to convert?
Thank you

Answer (score 81, accepted):

First changes your `year` formatter with `yyyy` and instead of using two `NSDateFormatter` use just one like this

```
let inputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let showDate = inputFormatter.dateFromString("07/21/2016")
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let resultString = inputFormatter.stringFromDate(showDate!)
print(resultString)
```

**For Swift3 and later**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let resultString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
print(resultString)
```

Comment: @Nirav D hey what if i want to convert the datepicker's date to 'yyyy-MM-dd' ?

Comment: @deltami Then set that format with DateFormatter and after that pass date picker date in `string(from:)` method of DateFormatter

Comment: what is the purpose of z"

Comment: @MuhammadShauket z is used for timezone but in question there is no time zone so I have corrected the edit of user IOSSingh

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 5+**

You can define a function like the one below:

```
// input string should always be in format "21/07/2016" ("dd/MM/yyyy")

func formattedDateFromString(dateString: String, withFormat format: String) -> String? {
    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    if let date = inputFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        outputFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return outputFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

You can use the above to pass an output format for your date string. Input format will always be dd/MM/yyyy. Then you use it as follows:

```
let stringA = formattedDateFromString("21/07/2016", withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
let stringB = formattedDateFromString("21/07/2016", withFormat: "MMM dd, yyyy")

NSLog("stringA: \(stringA)") // 2016-07-21
NSLog("stringB: \(stringB)") // Jul 21, 2016
```