# How to convert date from one format to another? Need to get date to "Tue Apr 3 22:10:06 2018" format

Tags: swift

How to convert "2018-04-03 22:10:06" to "Tue Apr 3 22:10:06 2018"? Obviously not those specific dates but that format.

I found this solution:

[How to convert date format from dd/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-dd in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503489/how-to-convert-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but I am unable to get it to the exact format.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` would seem to be in the input, `E MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy` would seem to be the output (referenced from [nsdateformatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com)

Comment: Do you know what is your date string timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just threw this into Playgrounds

```
let inFormat = DateFormatter()
inFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let date = inFormat.date(from: "2018-04-03 22:10:06")

let outFormat = DateFormatter()
outFormat.dateFormat = "E MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"
outFormat.string(from: date!)
```

It eventually outputs `Tue Apr 3 22:10:06 2018`

The formats were initial referenced from [nsdateformatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com)

This, of course, will use the current system `TimeZone` and `Locale`, so you may want to do some more investigation into that

Comment: Note that you need to set the locale to en_US_POSIX when parsing fixed date formats

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you explain why?  I have no issue, just want to know more

Comment: Otherwise it will be affected by the device locale and user settings and might crash if the device settings is set to 12hour (am/pm format)

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah, point - I did add that at the end as well "indirectly"

Comment: Btw generally when parsing date strings you should use UTC timezone instead of current

Comment: @LeoDabus Agreed, I've had it up to my back teeth of date/time values been represented as string without timezones and including "English" day/month values - there are standards for this people!